# [pyinstaller][open-cv] ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']

Tags: python, opencv, binary, pyinstaller

I am trying to build binary package of my code, the build process completed with success, but when I m trying to run the binary file, I got such an error:

```
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

Error log:
[image: Log Trace]

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by upgrading opencv-python and pyinstaller

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```

Comment: this solution does not work for me...