# opencv installation recursion

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu (18.04.3LTS) and Anaconda for Python. 
I am trying to install opencv and I followed the installation tutorial.
But when I type:

```
    import opencv
    import cv2
```

I get:

```
['/home/amyuval', '/home/amyuval/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/home/amyuval/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/home/amyuval/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '', '/home/amyuval/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/amyuval/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/amyuval/.ipython']
```

---

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>
     1 import cv2

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/cv2/__init__.py in <module>
     87     if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: DONE')
     88 
     89 bootstrap()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/cv2/__init__.py in bootstrap()
     21     if hasattr(sys, 'OpenCV_LOADER'):
     22         print(sys.path)
     23         raise ImportError('ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.')
     24     sys.OpenCV_LOADER = True
     25 

ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hi Yuval, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you check with `conda list` if you have multiple entries with `opencv` in them?

Comment: Hi, I have these enteries  
opencv-python             4.1.1.26                 pypi_0    pypi
openpyxl                  2.6.2                      py_0

Comment: Try to remove `import opencv`. You only have to use `import cv2`. Does that help?

Comment: I get this one: (thanks)
     55         if required:
---> 56             raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
     57 
     58     load_first_config(['config.py'], True)

ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.

Comment: Did you find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319943/pyinstalleropen-cv-importerror-opencv-loader-missing-configuration-file?

Comment: tried this now, didn't work

Comment: Try to run without ipython, otherwise file a bug at their Github.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows/MinGW, I also had a recursion problem (but not linked to `OpenCV_LOADER`).
The following did the trick (on Python main installation, but not on the MSys2 one...):

```
pip3 install opencv-python --upgrade --force-reinstall # [--user]
```