# Trying to run python script using OpenCV on Replit, throws ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']

Tags: python, opencv, replit

Trying to implement OCR into my simple python program, but Replit is being weird as usual with the module requirements. I get multiple errors, but the following shows first.

I tried to run this code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('/Users/marius/Desktop/jimdoo.png')
#Alternatively: can be skipped if you have a Blackwhite image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
gray, img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(img_bin)
kernel = np.ones((2, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
out_below = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print("OUTPUT:", out_below)
```

Not familiar with OCR so I can't MRE (sorry).

But this along with many other errors occured:

```
raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
```

Not very good at programming, what does this mean? Much thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[pyinstaller\]\[open-cv\] ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: \['config.py'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319943/pyinstalleropen-cv-importerror-opencv-loader-missing-configuration-file)

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. MRE means you reduce your code, so you figure out if it's **either** tesseract **or** opencv... also: this might be an issue with *replit*.