# import cv2 error 'missing configuration file: ['config']. Check Opencv installation'

Tags: python, opencv, replit

I should note I'm using an IDE (Repl.it)

in python shell i did:

```
pip3 install python-opencv.
```

This worked and seemed to install opencv.

However, `import cv2` returns:

```
Open CV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation
```

`pip install python-opencv` does not work.

Tried to reinstall opencv using pip3, i've got:

```
 error occurred during configuration: option use-feature: invalid choice: 'content-addressable-pool' (choose from 'fast-deps', 'truststore', 'no-binary-enable-wheel-cache')
```

I was hoping to simply install opencv.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319943/pyinstalleropen-cv-importerror-opencv-loader-missing-configuration-file

Answer (score 1):

Updating opencv to verson 23.0 worked for me

Answer (score -1):

To install opencv, try using `pip install opencv-python` instead of `python-opencv`, it should work.